# Нужна ли запятая после деепричастного оборота перед союзом «и»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот, и

Он лежал на полу, **чувствуя опустошение(,)** и медленно раскуривал сигарету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно! Закрыть деепричастный оборот необходимо. Вот если бы вместо глагола было второе деепричастие, запятая была бы не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо. Во втором варианте вы имели в виду что-то подобное: "Он лежал на полу, чувствуя опустошение и наслаждаясь тишиной"?

Comment: Ага, что-то такое. Только, по-моему, сложно чувствовать опустошение и одновременно чем-то наслаждаться. ;)

Comment: Спасибо. По поводу наслаждения согласен))

Answer (score 1):

Запятая, конечно же, необходима. Приведу несколько правил и соответствующих им примеров — для практики, сравнения и лучшего "уложения" материала.

> **1.** Деепричастный оборот, как правило, **обособляется** (выделяется запятыми) независимо от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому...

Шура слушал непонятное и красивое пение, **чувствуя себя размягченным, и** вдруг увидел, что Сторожев тоже крестится. [А. И. Слаповский. Большая Книга Перемен // «Волга», 2010]

> **4.** Два деепричастных оборота, соединенные неповторяющимся союзом ***и***, запятой не разделяются (как и другие однородные члены предложения в подобных случаях)...
> Но если союз ***и*** соединяет не деепричастные обороты, а другие конструкции (два сказуемых, две части сложносочиненного предложения), то запятая может стоять как перед союзом, так и после него (в соответствии с нужным правилом)...

― Но вы сказали, что непременно прочтёте, ― **чувствуя** близость провала **и** не совсем **понимая**, что делает, Олег подтолкнул папку назад. [Евгений Чижов. Перевод с подстрочника (2012)]

Он ходил, как в похмелье, **чувствуя** себя разбитым, **упрекая** себя в слабоволии, **скучая** по Рите **и боясь** с ней встретиться. [Н. Б. Лебина. Мужчина и женщина... (2014)]

Прижатая к нему всем телом, Айя задохнулась, **чувствуя** глубинную работу живых мехов, **и, положив** ладонь на грудь Леона, удивленно спрашивала себя: неужели это не бас? [Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын (2014)]

[Обособленные обстоятельства (деепричастные конструкции)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112)